# Api requests to servers

Tags: javascript, api

is there any sites or companies that store data for clients and allow us to make API requests from our applications to it? Im creating an electron app and want to verify user license keys by making a request to that server I set up on that company and receive if the key is listed.

is that method safe or is there a better way to verify license keys?

Comment: Are you asking for an _existing_ (API) service that will host your license keys for you?

Comment: @RocketHazmat yea doesn't need to be specifically for license keys just needs to be able to store data that I can make calls from an api and receive if the license key on that electron application is actually one that was issued.

Comment: U can host a mysql database on Heroku for free using the ClearDB add-on. With the database u could also deploy a simple endpoint script like `verifylicense.php` which would make an SQL query to the database and then it would return true or false depending whether the license key is found in the mySQL database.

Then, in your Electron app you would be able then make a GET/POST request to your enpoint `heroku.com/.../verifylicense.php` hosted on Heroku and get the response

Comment: You're looking for a PaaS or DBaaS.

Comment: "*Is there a better way to verify license keys?*" - do it completely offline. Sign the licence, verify the signature.

Comment: @Bergi by sign the license and verify it how would I do that offline? and would it be inside of the electron app?

Comment: Create a key pair, use the private one to sign licensee info, use the public one in the electron app to verify the signature of the licence file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar head-ache before, and one of the serverless and free applications you can use is [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI4ZK635ys8QIVled3Ch1L0gBvEAAYASAAEgLFmPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) by google.

It solves pretty much everything for you, and it has a free tier. You can authorize, and have some wild benefits like having a real-time datastore.

Even though it's googles, it's not widley popular, but I used it on a few test projects and I can recommend it. The other option of course is to make a backend yourself, like other comments have suggested.

Comment: So I’m familiar with firebase as I’ve used it for iOS development do you know exactly what part of firebase i would use like cloud fire store or real-time or some other form ?

Comment: Depends on what you want, that would be opinionated answer though. What I would do, is look at their pricing page, and features/access. I would use the new Firestore, since it's newer and a bit more cheaper, but I suggest you do some more research, and possibly take a look at other StackExchange communities for such opinions.